# Wysiwyg widget escaping character

Tags: magento2, widget, wysiwyg

I've created a widget with a wysiwyg inside it (with the class from this module Dmatthew\WidgetParameters\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Type\Wysiwyg)

BUT

When I'm adding my content, with the **strong**, **underline** or other html tag, it's working fine.

But if I change the color (it's adding a span) with **style="color:blue"**, the quote from the style is cutting my content.

Is there a way to prevent it ?

```
    public function prepareElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
{
    $editor = $this->factoryElement->create('editor', ['data' => $element->getData()])
        ->setLabel('')
        ->setForm($element->getForm())
        ->setWysiwyg(true)
        ->setConfig(
            $this->wysiwygConfig->getConfig([
                'add_variables' => false,
                'add_widgets' => false,
                'add_images' => false
            ])
        );

    if ($element->getRequired()) {
        $editor->addClass('required-entry');
    }

    $element->setData(
        'after_element_html', $this->_getAfterElementHtml() . $editor->getElementHtml()
    );
    $element->setValue(''); // Hides the additional label that gets added.

    return $element;
}
```

EDIT : this is what I get after saving my widget. All the word after I've added a color (with the wysiwyg) to the text is cut (and show span in wysiwyg)

[image]

[image]

EDIT 2 : this is my widget definition :

Video
    Vidéo et description

```
    <parameter name="url" xsi:type="text" required="true" visible="true">
        <label translate="true">Identifiant Youtube de la vidéo</label>
    </parameter>


    <parameter name="subtitle" xsi:type="text" required="true" visible="true">
        <label translate="true">Sous titre</label>
    </parameter>

    <parameter name="content" xsi:type="block" visible="true" required="true">
        <label translate="true">Contenu associé à la vidéo</label>
        <block class="Dmatthew\WidgetParameters\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Type\Wysiwyg"/>
    </parameter>

</parameters>
```

Comment: Please post the content you've done in your wysiwyg, I can't see where you tried to add style in current post.

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: What is the data length for the wysiwyg content on your database?

Comment: I don't know, i've updated my question with my widget definition

Comment: Could this append because my wysiwig is from a custom widget and the widget is in a bloc ? because in **admin/admin/widget_instance** this is working fine !

Comment: Seems like you didn't assigned proper data type to the relevent database column.
Try to set any larger content and check if issue is of style attribute or content lenght.
If you aren't able to save any largent content too than most propebly you just have to change your relevent database column type to text.

Comment: Where do I do this ? Even if I set a simple "test" in the wisiwyg, none of my data are saved